# When or Why should state-checking functions be typically used?

Tags: java, api, design-patterns

Assume we have an API.

```
interface Graph {
    boolean checkIfPathExists(source, destination);
    List<Integer> getPath(source, destination);
}
```

Which one of the following would be the best / recommended implementation.

Option 1: Enforce a check to verify path exists. If checkPath is not called prior then throw exception.

```
Graph g = new GraphImpl(graph);
if (g.checkIfPathExists(s, d)) {
   List path = g.getPath(s, d);
}
```

Option 2: Dont enforce function sequence. If getPath is called then, let getPath() internally call checkIfPathExists() and return empty collection if checkIfPathExists() returns false;

```
Graph g = new GraphImpl(graph);
List path = g.getPath(s, d);
```

In my opinion, Option2 looks good to me but only issue I have with it, is a redundant / unnecessary call to 'state-check method like 'checkIfPathExists()'.  Ideally, This is not what getPath() should be doing. It should just be returning the path.

1. Which is a better implementation option1 or option2 ?
2. If option2 was a better option then would it have been a better design choice to not add 'checkIfPathExists' as public interface at all ? To make a question more generic state check methods appear like 'hasNext()' if not enforced appear unnecessary. Even to iterate through a list we could get the size of list and use a for loop until i <= size, and never use hasNext() at all.
   In a nutshell - what is the use of state-checking functions if they are not enforced ?
3. Any 'real-life' example where state-checking methods are enforced ? Meaning, not calling them prior results in an exception?

Comment: I agree with you. I don't see the need for the extra function call to 'checkIfPathExists()'.

Comment: What is the point of saying the api can't be modified?  It seems either unrelated to your question or makes your question pointless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether or not to have a `checkIfExists` or `hasNext` function that exist only to "protect" the call to another function really depends on the cost and consequence of the protected function.

If `getPath` is very expensive and `checkIfPathExists` is very quick, then it makes sense to have both functions.  Enforcing a call to `checkIfPathExists` for the same parameters prior to `getPath`, however, is unusual and seems unnecessary since if you can put that mechanism in then you could also cache its results and thus not need to actually enforce it in `getPath`, just use the cache if it is available or perform the call.

In the case of an `Iterator` with `hasNext`, part of the reason for this is that the call to `next` has consequences and an unknown cost (could be iterating anything from an array to a singly linked list to something using a network connection).  Once `next` is called you also cannot go back, so an Iterator needs to support it in the case where the logic of handling the current element changes depending on if there is a next element.

If you are worried specifically about performance, then you can provide two methods, one which assumes a path does exist (`checkIfPathExists` was already called and returned true) so does not needs to perform the existence check, and one which makes no such assumption and will call `checkIfPathExists` before searching.  Document the methods appropriately in the javadoc and users will generally use them correctly.

**To answer your question directly**, *option 2* would be generally preferred since it is more expected and does not require the extra code complexity to verify the sequence of calls.  Documentation stipulating the advantages (if they exist) of calling `checkIfPathExists` first would suffice to waylay any concerns with this option.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what kind of API is this, but I don't think that it is an exceptional situation that a path doesn't exist between two vertices, so throwing and exception doesn't seem to be a good idea.

If you are striving for a [minimal interface](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/MinimalInterface.html) then you can drop `boolean checkIfPathExists(source, destination);` from your API and  use Guava's [Optional](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Optional.html) class as a return value of `getPath(source, destination);` to indicate the a path might not exists between two vertices. Keep in mind you have to differentiate between the non-existing path and zero length path.

On the otherhand, if you would like to provide a [human interface](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/HumaneInterface.html) then you can keep `boolean checkIfPathExists(source, destination);` as a convenience method to check if a path exists between to vertices without forcing clients to actually retrieve it (this might even provide some room for performance optimization).  Note that this is only a *convenience* method, it is not mandatory to call it before `getPath` and I think that would not even be a good design since it would result in [sequential coupling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_coupling).

Finally, if you can not decide which would be better, then stick to minimal API, it's easier to extend later. Remember the golden rule by Joshua Bloch:

> When in doubt leave it out